# void* pointer arithmetic, cannot swap float values

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers, pointer-arithmetic

recently, i was curious on how `qsort()` sorts without passing specific type, thus i'm trying to reverse an array without knowing / caring it's type.

i was told you can do pointer arithmetic if you cast `void *` into a `char *`.

```
void swap(void *a, void *b)
{
    char tmp = *(char *)a;
    *(char *)a = *(char *)b;
    *(char *)b = tmp;
}
```

the function `swap()` works well with type `int` & `char` but not with `float` nor `double`.

i don't know why this is the case, but i saw an implementation of swapping with `memcpy()`, with that, i implented so:

```
void __swap(void *a, void *b, size_t size)
{
    char buf[size];
    memcpy(buf, a, size);
    memcpy(a, b, size);
    memcpy(b, buf, size);
}
```

reverse function implementation using `swap()`:

```
void arr_reverse(void *arr, size_t size, size_t len)
{
    for (size_t i = 0, j = len - 1; i < len / 2; i++, j--)
        swap(arr + (i * size), arr + (j * size));
}
```

reverse function implementation using `__swap()`:

```
void arr_reverse(void *arr, size_t size, size_t len)
{
    for (size_t i = 0, j = len - 1; i < len / 2; i++, j--)
        __swap(arr + (i * size), arr + (j * size), size);
}
```

`__swap()` works greatly, but i don't know why this is the case, **so the question is**, what's the difference between `swap()` and `__swap()`?

> i'm assuming there's something to do with type sizes

Comment: hint: `swap()` works only when swapping `char`s and for `int` only because your machine is LE and you used only the first 8 LSB bits to store a value (assumption which is broken for `double and `float`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `void *` arithmetics is an undefined behaviour. It is a **GCC extension** and it is not allowed by the C standard.
2. `__swap`, and `swap` are doing something completely different. The first is swapping whole `chunks` of memory of the `size` len. Latter one is swapping only first chars leaving the rest untouched for longer types (like double or float)

```
void swap(void *a, void *b)
{
    char tmp = *(char *)a;
    *(char *)a = *(char *)b;
    *(char *)b = tmp;
}


void __swap(void *a, void *b, size_t size)
{
    char buf[size];
    memcpy(buf, a, size);
    memcpy(a, b, size);
    memcpy(b, buf, size);
}


void invalid_arr_reverse(void *vp, size_t size, size_t len)
{
    unsigned char *arr = vp;
    for (size_t i = 0, j = len - 1; i < len / 2; i++, j--)
        swap(arr + (i * size), arr + (j * size));
}


void arr_reverse(void *vp, size_t size, size_t len)
{
    unsigned char *arr = vp;
    for (size_t i = 0, j = len - 1; i < len / 2; i++, j--)
        __swap(arr + (i * size), arr + (j * size), size);
}

void printarr(uint32_t *arr, size_t size )
{
    while(size--) printf("0x%08x\n" ,(unsigned)*arr++);
}


int main(void)
{
    uint32_t arr[4] = {0x00112233, 0x44556677, 0x8899aabb, 0xccddeeff};
    uint32_t arr1[4] = {0x00112233, 0x44556677, 0x8899aabb, 0xccddeeff};

    invalid_arr_reverse(arr, 4, 4);
    printarr(arr, 4);
    arr_reverse(arr1, 4, 4);
    printarr(arr1, 4);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/z1sYrPj6G

Byte swapping function has to be written different way:

```
void arr_reverse(void *vp, size_t size, size_t len)
{
    unsigned char *arr = vp;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
        for(size_t j = 0; j < size; j++)
            swap(arr + (i * size) + j, arr + (len - i -1) * size + j);
}
```

Comment: Using `i < j` in the loop conditions is simpler than `i < len / 2`.

Comment: The C standard does not prohibit `void *` arithmetic. It does not define it and requires a diagnostic but does not disallow it. A program that uses `void *` arithmetic and is otherwise conforming to the C standard is conforming to the C standard, as defined in C 2018 clause 4. The C standard does not define a complete programming language. It defines a base for a language that is intended to be extended, and extensions are allowed. The base language is not useful for practical purposes beyond simple text interactions and abstract calculations, so it must be extended to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

This implementation of `swap` swaps one byte.
That's fine for chars.
That may *look* fine for small integers, but as soon as your integers get greater than 255, you will see it fail, too.

Note how `__swap` has the third argument, `size`.
When you swap two items, you need to know *three* pieces of information:

- where is the first item,
- where is the second item,
- what is the size of both items.

So, a generic function may not know the exact type, but it still needs to know the size of that type in bytes.